# user entered sentence , and i want to count no of words

Tags: string, count

user entered sentence , and i want to count no of words in it
 ex: Shsssssssssh ... I am hunting wabbits. Heh Heh Heh Heh ...
i get the words but i want not to count (... )

```
string sentence ;
 char space[] = " " ;
 int noWords = 0;
while(getline(cin , sentence) )
{
    noWords = 0;
    char* arr = new char[sentence.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i <sentence.length(); i++)
    {
        arr[i] = sentence[i];
    }

    char* token;
    token = strtok(arr , space);

    while (token != NULL)
    {

        noWords ++;
        token = strtok(NULL , space);
    }
    cout<<noWords<<endl;
}
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, be sure to tag your language when your looking for code help.

Comment: what happens if you just do:

printf("Number of words is %d\n", noWords);

I'm just assuming C++